# Graph complexity

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Can someone please explain briefly or direct me to some relevant tutorials/material   what we maen by complexity of a graph('graph' of graph theory) .It seems there is no one definition and that is confusing me .I would be highly obliged for any help in this regard

Comment: Try:  https://www.amazon.com/Random-Graphs-Complex-Networks-Probabilistic/dp/110717287X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1HXZ3V9KGK2VR&dchild=1&keywords=random+graphs+and+complex+networks&qid=1591546807&sprefix=%22complex+graph%22+n%2Caps%2C287&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting as an answer since too long for a comment*

---

I believe different people may have different answers to this question. From [this](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r9.pdf) paper,

> "... complexity of a graph has been measured in several different ways. For example, the complexity of a graph has been defined to be the number of its spanning trees. It has been defined to be the value of a certain formula involving the number of vertices, edges, and proper paths in a graph. It has also been defined as the number of Boolean operations, based on a pre-determined set of Boolean operators (usually union and intersection), necessary to construct the graph from a fixed generating set of graphs".

The paper then goes on to define yet *another* method for measuring the complexity of a graph.

According to [this](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/graph-compl.pdf) article,

> Computational complexity of graphs is the smallest number of union and intersection operations required to generate them when starting from simplest sets of edges: stars or cliques.

[Another opinion](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_we_measure_the_complexity_of_a_graph) is to use [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) to determine

> how long is a minimal program to produce the graph?

I am sure there are several other points of view on this as well.

Comment: Another one that comes to mind is the difference $|V|-|E|+1$, which comes up for instance in the evolution of random graphs. This is a useful measure of complexity in that case because when the giant component appears, it has complexity approaching infinity, but other connected components have complexity either $0$ or $1$ (with high probability).